# When are repository interfaces (jpaRepository) beans created?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

Even though my interface MonRepo (which extends JpaRepository) is not annotated with any annotation that tells spring to create a bean for this class (eg. Service, Controller, Component etc.). How is the bean for this class created. I know for sure that a bean is created because I have autowired monRepo in another class and it is working perfectly fine.

MonRepo

```
public interface MonRepo extends MongoRepository<Mon, Long> {
    public List<Mon> findAllBymId(@Param("mId") Long mId);
}
```

Class in which monRepo is autowired

```
@Component("iRuleEngine")
public class RuleEngine implements IRuleEngine {

    @Autowired
    private MonRepo monRepo;
.
.
.
}
```

I have not used the enableJpaRepository annotation anywhere but my class.
MonRepo does lie in my component scan scope.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? Boot automatically activates Spring Data for the  module and uses the package of the main application configuration as packe to scan for repositories. This can be overriden by explicitly using `@Enable…Repositories`.

Comment: Yes I am using spring boot. If I don't use spring boot do I need to @Repository annotation explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have configured package which contains MonRepo as repository package with @EnableJpaRepositories annotation or corresponding XML configuration.

As stated in [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html):

> By default the infrastructure picks up every interface extending the
>   persistence technology-specific Repository subinterface located under
>   the configured base package and creates a bean instance for it.

Comment: I have not used EnableJpaRepository, only ComponentScan has been used. Would using EnableJpaRepository be redundant in this case.?